# Why did Wally have his powers even after Savitar died?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

We have seen that when Flash had an amnesia, Wally lost his powers. But when Savitar died, that means he was never created in the future, and hewill never plan on creating Wally as a speedster to take his place in Speed Force. That means Wally shouldn't be a speedster, right?

Comment: the speed force did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flash messed up its time travel logic in season 3. In episode 21 of S03 "Cause and Effect", for plot purposes, Savitar loses his memories and therefore events lead to Wally not getting his powers. Ok.

So, then using the same logic, Wally currently shouldn't have his powers, right? How is he a speedster now?

Season 2 had already given the answer.

While in S02 episode 11 "The Reverse Flash Returns", it is clearly explained by Harry that Nora Allen's death is a fixed point in the timeline, and stopping the timeline remnant Thawne would not change what happened in the past. Granted, the future is in a constant state of flux, but the past would remain unchanged iff a time traveler does not tamper with the said time in the past.

I don't know why this is such a thing now - using the same logic, in S01, Thawne getting erased, should have resulted in Barry losing his powers, since Thawne would never create the Flash, and Barry's mom should have walked from the grave, as Thawne would never kill Nora Allen.

The final solution is -

A speedster getting erased from existence at a certain point in time does not affect his actions that had taken place in history. The savitar that gave Wally his powers has become a time remnant, as in he was already a time remnant, but now he is a time remnant of the Savitar timeline, where he exists to solely to serve his purpose to the timeline, so that paradoxes do not occur. The speed force preserves such timeline remnants, to prevent further paradoxes that would impact a certain timeline.

I have a really clean and simple solution if you've gotten tired and confused  due to the answer that I gave and have scrolled down

- **FORGET SEASON 3 EVER HAPPENED.**

Comment: Barry didn't lose his abilities immediately. Which means wally could experience it later.

Comment: Barry didn't lose his powers at all. What I meant to say was, using the Wally-losing-powers-due-to-savitar-being-erased logic, Barry should've lost his powers too, but he didn't. The same goes for Wally also.

Comment: No he was. he was forgetting everything. and soon he would lose his powers. Even in Flash point paradox movie, the character of flash lost his abilities and so had to eletrocute himself with lightning with batman's help. in the arrowverse also, it was shown that his memories were being replaced. and soon he would have completely lost his powers.it was specifically mentioned that he would no longer be the flash if he didnt release thorn. the time gap is the only difference here, but it was needed for the plot, so he could stop changing past without all that lightning nuisance like in the movie.

Comment: so the argument would be more along the lines of why not immediate and why the gradual loss. The answer for that could be because, He has time till the time catches upto him I guess? this is purely speculation since, barry and thorn are both being affected but barry still can stop it by releasing thorn. so basically, till thorn is alive, they have a chance of going back to keep the timeline intact.

Comment: and so the answer to he original question is simply put, we cant be sure till the next season for the explanation. or also possible they became fixed points and taken care of by the time remnants as you said in ur answer.

Comment: That was because of Flashpoint. I'm talking in season 1, where Barry should have lost his powers since Eobard was erased from existence (Since Eobard is the one who creates the Flash). But he didn't. Same thing with Wally. Wally wouldn't lose his powers because Savitar got erased.

Comment: but that's why the black hole was created. it became a completely different timeline. here also, we might see some consequences in wally's timeline in the next season. or maybe we already did because the time prison for savitar was unstable and barry had to go. and the rest was normalised just as barry kept his powers after closing the black hole.

Comment: Adding onto the list of paradoxes: in S03E01 Flashpoint, Barry restores the timeline where his mother dies AND where Eddie kills himself to erase Eobard from existence. Shouldn't Reverse Flash have disappeared when they returned to the present?

Comment: @Arc676 Eobard existed as a time remnant, from that moment on, which is the reason he escaped his erasure and Zoom constantly chased after him.

Answer (score 0):

They just messed up. Or didn’t care. I think in episode cause and effect they had Wally lose his powers just so he couldn’t fight in the episode. When savitar was alive and couldn’t remember anything he never gave Wally powers, okay that’s fine but when he dies because Barry never created him same rules should appl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).